# N-letter Substrings in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I'm working on an extension of the basic Word Count example in Hive - in particular, extracting all n-length substrings (n will be decided before execution).

So far, all I can manage to come up with is a brute force (and incomplete) method (this is for substring of length 2, eg).

```
 CREATE TABLE lines (line STRING);
 CREATE TABLE word_counts AS
  SELECT regexp_extract(word, '([a-zA-Z]{2})', 1) word, count(1) AS count FROM
   (SELECT explode(split(line, '\\s')) AS word FROM docs) w
 GROUP BY word
 ORDER BY word;
```

Obv, this just returns the very first substring of length 2. Regexp_extract doesn't seem to have a way to return all matches, and there's no regex_extract_all equivalent, either. Here's a list of Hive string functions, but I'm just not sure how to incorporate variables into these ([Hive String Functions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF)) I don't see a way to loop, so, I'm fresh out of ideas.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you want variables you're looking for `--hiveconf` passed at the query execution using `-f` or `-e`

Comment: Honestly, I would write a UDF for this

Comment: I would if I could... hence the question.

Comment: Meaning that you don't know how, or cannot?

Comment: Don't know how. I'm new to Hive.

Comment: @cricket_007 I'll take a look. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried something like `explode(split(line, '\\w{${hiveconf:n}}'))`? https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+VariableSubstitution

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156792/discussion-between-dylan-larkin-and-cricket-007).

Comment: Java UDFs are hard (it requires package imports and junk). I'd stick to Python, if you're comfortable with it. https://acadgild.com/blog/hive-udf-in-python/... Anyways, you cannot loop - everything is a table: so you always act on whole columns, not rows (unless you explode() one row, but again, that explodes a column of arrays  into a longer column)